# MainWindow() and InitializeComponent() building in WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, onload

This code is from my C# WPF application:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    status("Getting dl links");
    getLinks();
}
```

The procedure `getLinks` currently displays a couple of links in a messagebox. Those links are displayed in a messagebox *before* the WPF application becomes visible.
In this is case not a problem, but how would I show progress (like a progressbar) of any
procedure I want to load at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can do it. To simplify it a bit, I added the controls directly in the `MainWindow` constructor, but I would prefer to do this with XAML.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.Height = 40;
    progressBar.Width = 200;
    progressBar.Margin = new Thickness(100, 100, 100, 100);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // getLinks();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar.Value += 20; }));

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    });

    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(progressBar);

    Content = stackPanel;

}
```

I first add a `ProgressBar` somewhere on the interface to make it visible for this demo and then I add it to a new `StackPanel`, it could be any panel at all, in this case it doesn't matter.

To load the links on another thread, I create a new `Task`, this is a part of the `TPL` ([Task Parallel Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions#Task_Parallel_Library)) in .NET 4.0. In this case I am simulating that `getLinks()` takes 5 * 500 milliseconds to run and that it in fact is five links that will be loaded, hence 20% each iteration.

What I do then is that I add `20` to the `progressBar` value, which indicates that it increased with 20%.

This line might confuse you a bit

`Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar.Value += 20; }));`

But it is in fact quite common when you do cross-thread programming with GUI. So the problem is that you are on another thread here, we started of a `Task` that will run on a separate thread, and you cannot update your UI thread from another thread. So what you need is something called a `Dispatcher`, and this is accessable from within your `Window`-class.

Then you `Invoke` an action on it, which means that you simply say "Run this piece of code on this thread for me".

And if you want to display a `MessageBox` when everything is loaded, you can simply add a `MessageBox.Show("Loaded!");` after the `for`-loop.

Comment: Is it smart to put Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { } );
around euh, all procedures?

Comment: @krtek, Well, both Yes and No. Do you want all procedures to run `async`? Then Yes otherwise No. But this is one example of how to run things in the background, you can also look at the `BackgroundWorker` that Robert Levy suggested. But what I would probably do if I have a lot of procedures that run in a sequence is that I put them together and run one method `async` that invokes all of them, do you understand how I mean? On the other hand, I wouldn't create a background worker for each procedure either. You can always refactor code, make it work, then refactor it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Damn, I wish I could have you standing next to me my whole life :3

Answer (score 1):

Any 'loading' tasks need to happen on a background thread (see the BackgroundWorker class - google for lots of examples).  That way, the UI thread is free to show your window and update your window with status messages.  Otherwise, the UI thread is blocked from doing anything until your loading is complete.